# CPLEX OPL Returning a set index with a condition

Tags: set, tuples, cplex, opl

I have a tuple as below and I want to return the first element's TimePeriodID whose ActivePeriod value is "YES". Tried to use first, and minl & ord functions, but it did not work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
tuple timeperiod {
  string TimePeriodID;
  string TimePeriodName;
  float CurrencyRate;
  float Rank;
  string ActivePeriod;
}
{timeperiod} TimePeriods = ...;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
tuple timeperiod {
  string TimePeriodID;
  string TimePeriodName;
  float CurrencyRate;
  float Rank;
  string ActivePeriod;
}
{timeperiod} TimePeriods = {<"A","B",1.0,2.3,"NO">,<"V","B",4.0,2.3,"YES">,<"D","B",4.0,2.3,"YES">};

string answer=first({i | i in TimePeriods : i.ActivePeriod=="YES"}).TimePeriodID;

execute
{
writeln(answer);
}
```

gives

V

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful.